# Removing the google chrome profile icon

Tags: google-chrome

[image]

Few days ago this blue profile thing was slapped on chrome symbols on my computer.
I do not like the way it looks, is it possible to have the bare chrome symbol?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In chrome settings you can see multiple account names. If you delete all but one, that blue symbol disappears.

Comment: this works.Click on your icon on the top right and click "Manage People". You should see the accounts.

Comment: I resisted this solution because I thought I would not be able to use the Google account associated with the deleted profile. But that turns out not to be true: you can use different accounts even under the single remaining profile, so as a solution this works quite fine.

Answer (score 19):

For Windows 10:
Right-click on the taskbar and go to Taskbar Settings and turn off "Show badges on taskbar buttons"

Comment: Consider adding some reference and proof supporting what you state

Comment: This doesn't work, the icon is still displayed

Comment: @szx The icon displayed at this time is the icon of the shortcut itself. In Windows, the icon of the shortcut can be modified at will.

Comment: That just made the icon smaller for me.

Comment: Not to mention this is unbelievably heavy handed and affects all apps. Don't do this.

Comment: This may not be the best answer to the question as specifically asked, but it did help me get what I wanted (removal of the user badge from the taskbar icon), so I'm upvoting.  As far as "affects all apps" yes, it does...and I'm fine with that. :-)

Comment: It removes the bottom-right badge but for whatever reason Chrome actually has two badges: one on the bottom right that Windows somehow controls, as well as a smaller badge on the top right of each taskbar entry.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `%LOCALAPPDATA%/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Google Profile Picture.png` with a transparent image, so it will be "hidden" :)

Comment: This is the best answer

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked. I've tried a number of things and it doesn't seem like it's possible to disable this.

Of course, if you only have one profile it will work.

Comment: Having a single profile works well, though. You can still use multiple Google accounts under a single profile. Of course, if you really want to keep complete sets of browser configurations, then you need multiple profiles, but I would imagine that is quite rare.

Comment: Not that rare if you have multiple people using the same computer (but don't have their own login to that computer.) This is a bane of my existence.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did. Right-click the shortcut, select "Properties", and then "Change Icon". The shortcut uses an icon on your profile (%LocalAppData%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default or other Profiles), and you just need to select the original Chrome's icon. You'll need unpin it from Taskbar first to see the change.

Answer (score -3):

What I did for this is open Chrome:

1. Right-click on the Chrome icon with the profile icon
2. Right-click on the Chrome icon with the profile icon again
3. Click "Properties"
4. Click "Change icon"
5. Go to the directory of Chrome.exe
6. Choose chrome.exe
7. Choose the preffered icon
   It worked for me.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/968649/ven) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/968650/ven). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score -3):

What worked for me:
Right Click profile icon in Chrome browser > Go to Manage People > Remove extra people profiles so that it just has one profile > icon gets removed